# How to call a java class methods from java script which will be used in html page?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I want to use some java object value inside my java script .Is there any way to do that.
After searching in web i found that oracle has some documentation on that

**http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html**

But I tried same thing in my html web pages it seems  that web page results parsing error and  did not display anything.

Note-Here I donot want to use jsp servelet.Iam very much know to this fact that javascript is a client side technology but please confirm me if there is any way possible to call Please have a look what i have tried so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

importPackage(java.lang);
// Import the java.lang.String class
importClass(java.lang.String);

var StringArray = Java.type("java.lang.String[]");
var a = new StringArray(5);

// Set the value of the first element
a[0] = "Scripting is great!";
// Print the length of the array
print(a.length);
document.write(a.length);


// You can include version to along with any above condition.
document.write("<br /> Browser version info : " + version );
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Please donot down vote I am prettymuch new to Web programming basically i work on RCP (Rich client platform application )Desktop edition

Comment: Did you explore JSP?

Comment: I donot want to do it in jsp as i am doing it for My RCP application welcome screenAnd as per my knowledge jsp needs a server to reside

Comment: Basically It is welcome screen which i want to display at start up But there i need some information from java method.

Comment: You can use LiveConnect to do so:
https://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/

Comment: But it is now obsolete

Comment: I am not sure about this but this is what I've found:
http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nashorn/
It looks like it can be used with Java 8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71846/discussion-between-rajesh-and-aayush).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted is Rhino or Nashorn Javascript engine for Java. It's called from Java. It doesn't support `document` object. This code can be used in desktop or server applications which don't know anything about a browser.

[Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/porting_from_the_browser_to) is described how to imitate `document` object to let its usage in Nashorn. It's written mainly for porting reasons. E.g. if you have many scripts previously written for browser (which contain `document` object) and now you need to port these scripts to desktop application then you're able to imitate that object.

If you'd like to use Nashorn in a browser instead of desktop application, you can pass real `document` object to Java applet and then pass it to Nashorn as described in that link. You need such a schema of calling: Browser (Javascript) -> Applet (Java) -> Nashorn (Javascript). It's strange, isn't it? And redundant.

So, the simple way is just to create an applet and interact with it. Take a look at this [approach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html). But there will be no `importPackage` methods. You'll have to write Java code in applet.

Comment: Also, take a look at this class: [JSObject](https://jdk6.java.net/nonav/plugin2/liveconnect/jsobject-javadoc/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html). You can obtain `window` object through it and pass the object to Nashorn. So, your code would become valid. Wow, how complicated that is.